# Obscure movie from 1980s/1990s - Cartoon (maybe anime) with girl

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

I remember watching a movie as a child, in the 80s or early 90s (I'm 27 now) and for the life of me I can't remember the title (or a lot of details about it). So I'm hoping the few and random bits I do remember might trigger someone's memory and they can help me remember the title.

I remember it had a girl, maybe a teenager, that is on a mission or journey and she meets a handsome man along the way and he tries to tempt her and distract her from her mission. Maybe it was a drink that puts her to sleep. I think in the beginning of the movie she may have been an animal or something and was transformed into a human. It doesn't take place on earth. And that is about all I can remember. The part I remember most vividly is the handsome man that tries to tempt her.

Comment: More details will help. Describe the handsome man. What color hair does he have? Skin? Clothes? Any defining marks like scars or tattoos? Is the film overall dark or bright? Is the film slow paced or fast paced? Any splits you make in the search space will make this easier.

Answer (score 8):

It could conceivably be [The Last Unicorn](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084237/), but it's a stretch.  The movie starts with a unicorn looking for more of her kind and she is eventually transformed into a human female.  There is a handsome man (a prince, in this case) who falls in love with her and she gradually forgets her origins- she wants to stay human.

The animation style always reminded me of anime, hence the suggestion.

Comment: Good call, that sounds like it.

Comment: It could be, but the same can be said of The Little Mermaid. There are lots of movies with this overall theme.

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for ["The Fantastic Adventures of Unico"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083258/), an anime originally released in 1981 and based on a manga by Osamu Tezuka.

In one segment of the film, Unico - a baby unicorn with the power to make people happy - meets a kitten named Katy (Chao in the original) who wants to become a witch. Katy thinks an old woman living in the cottage in the woods is a witch, even though Unico insists she's not. To make his friend happy, Unico transforms her into a young woman, and Katy lives with the old woman, takes care of her house, and so on, although she still has cat-like traits such as wanting to chase mice. One day in the forest, Katy meets Baron de Ghost, a handsome man on horseback who invites her to his castle. She thoughtlessly runs away, abandoning the old woman. Baron de Ghost gets her drunk, seduces her, and turns into a powerful demon-like creature before Unico defeats him.

It matches on having a heroine who is an animal transformed into a human, who is distracted and tempted by a handsome human male.

[You can watch it on Youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuNdW9fBJCY) The Katy story starts at 32 minutes in.